# 301 rediect home page to new domain dealing with 'www / no www' and '/index.html'

Tags: .htaccess, http-status-code-301

were moving the url of a site so we've set up 301 redirects from each page to its equivalent page on the new site. The syntax we are using for this is :

```
redirect 301 /about-us.html http://newiste.co.uk/about-us.html
```

what im having trouble working out is how to send the old home page - http://oldsite.co.uk to http://newsite.co.uk - since the home page is at domain.co.uk with out /index.html also there is a similar problem with www. vs non www.

would configuring my .htaccess file on the old domain like this be the proper way to do it ?

```
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.oldsite\.co\.uk)(:80)? [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://oldsite.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
order deny,allow

redirect 301 / http://newsite.co.uk
redirect 301 /about-us.html http://newsite.co.uk/about-us.html
redirect 301 /contact-us.html http://newsite.co.uk/contact-us.html
redirect 301 /bespoke-furniture.html http://newsite.co.uk/bespoke-furniture.html
redirect 301 /how-we-work.html http://newsite.co.uk/discovery.html
```

Comment: You need to redirect only specific (listed) URLs to the new site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To redirect root document, you can use following rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://newsite.co.uk/ [R=301,L]
```

Also a comment to your:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.oldsite\.co\.uk)(:80)? [NC]
```

Port number is never part of the HTTP_HOST variable, most efficient is to avoid using regular expressions if possible:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.oldsite.co.uk [NC]
```

Your code `redirect 301 / http://newsite.co.uk` will redirect everything, not only the root `/`

Comment: thanks, so would i have it like this                           RewriteRule ^/?$ http://newsite.co.uk/ [R=301,L]
redirect 301 /about-us.html http://newsite.co.uk/about-us.html             and have a new like starting redirect 301 for each page ?

Comment: @sam if you need to redirect only *some* pages, then yes, you need to list them as you have it now. Just remove the `redirect 301 / http://newsite.co.uk` and add the quoted `RewriteRule`

Comment: sorry, please ignore this comment